# Do I need to create a variable/object to return when catching an exception?

Tags: php, exception

I have this way of handling exceptions for some time now, but lately has been bothering me.

```
    protected function sendPostmarkBatch($envios_preparados)
    {
        try {
            $client = new PostmarkClient($this->postmarkToken());

            $sendResult = $client->sendEmailBatchWithTemplate($envios_preparados);

        } catch (PostmarkException $e) {
            log_message('error', 'HTTP: ' . $e->httpStatusCode . ' MESSAGE: ' . $e->message . ' ERROR CODE: ' . $e->postmarkApiErrorCode);

            $sendResult = new stdClass();
            $sendResult->ErrorCode = $e->postmarkApiErrorCode;
        } catch (Exception $generalException) {
            log_message('error', 'GENERAL EXCEPTION: ' . $generalException);

            $sendResult = new stdClass();
            $sendResult->ErrorCode = '1';           
        }

        return $sendResult;     
    }
```

Is it really necessary to create the object or variable $sendResult at 'catch' to return it or it's already created even if 'try' fails? Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: `Is it really necessary to create the object or variable $sendResult at 'catch' to return it or it's already created even if 'try' fails?`...well a simple test would reveal that to you. But yeah you need to create it, unless you create it before the try starts

Comment: Thanks. I'm almost certain I've tried it and that's why I'm doing it that way. It's just one of those cases when you start doubting the way you've been doing things for so long and maybe there's a better way.

Comment: How about just doing $sendResult = $e, $sendResult = $generalException at 'catch'?

Comment: Nevermind, answered below

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary.

I'm not sure if it's suits your logic, but you can do something like this:

```
    protected function sendPostmarkBatch($envios_preparados)
    {
        $sendResult = new stdClass();
        
        try {
            $client = new PostmarkClient($this->postmarkToken());

            $sendResult = $client->sendEmailBatchWithTemplate($envios_preparados);

        } catch (PostmarkException $e) {
            log_message('error', 'HTTP: ' . $e->httpStatusCode . ' MESSAGE: ' . $e->message . ' ERROR CODE: ' . $e->postmarkApiErrorCode);

            $sendResult->ErrorCode = $e->postmarkApiErrorCode;
        } catch (Exception $generalException) {
            log_message('error', 'GENERAL EXCEPTION: ' . $generalException);

            $sendResult->ErrorCode = '1';           
        }

        return $sendResult;     
    }
```

If `$client->sendEmailBatchWithTemplate($envios_preparados)` fails, your `$sendResult` variable won't be overwrited.

Comment: Thanks! Now, this just occurred to me. How about just doing $sendResult = $e, $sendResult = $generalException at 'catch'?

Comment: I'd not suggest doing that.
As I see `sendPostmarkBatch` method should return result of sending the email. If it returns an exception it will cause an ambiguity in your code.
// Btw, I advise you to read about the SOLID principles, as in the case of returning `$e`, it seems to me, principle "S" will be violated

Comment: You're right. The response structure will not be equivalent.